# Error while sending HTTP GET requests using Volley in Android

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am using volley in my android application to make an HTTP GET request. I get the following error -

```
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for D/LOG ENTRY(21952): com.android.volley.ServerError
```

When I use a REST Client to make the same HTTP request it is successful.

My Volley request code is -

```
RequestQueue queue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(appContext);
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
                       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                               Log.d("Response",response.toString());
                          }
                       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                               Log.d("LOG ENTRY",error.toString());                     
                           }
                       }) {

                   @Override
                   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                       HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       headers.put("clientSecret", appContext.getString(R.string.username));
                       return headers;
                   }
               };

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
       queue2.add(req);
```

Please could you help figure out why the error is happening

Comment: What is the link you're using? Error 500 is an internal server error (error is on server side).

Comment: I thought so too but when I use the same link on a REST API Client it works so not sure what the issue is

Comment: I am sending 10 similar HTTP requests, everytime for some of them randomly I get this error and for others I dont. and when I do getCause() or getStackTrace() its empty

Comment: Have you tried JsonArrayRequest rather than JsonObjectRequest?

Comment: I did, getting the same error

Comment: Can it be because I of the number of requests I am making. Whenever my requests are restricted to 5, I never get an error as soon as it becomes more than 5 or 6 I start getting errors

Comment: The server might have restrictions on how many requests you can do in a certain amount of time. Try doing multiple requests in Postman in the same span of time to see if you get the 500 error.

Comment: @AubtinSamai Yes that was the reason. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error is an internal server error, so it is an error on the server sided code. The cause of this (in this case) is you're  going over the API request limit.

The Volley code is fine in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
queue2.add(req);
```

Add this line:

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(queue2);
```